# How to prevent lose event while replacing the area where the event registered

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, events

I have a click event created by plugin and after I load $.ajax and only replaced(update) the area where contain the click event, the event will lost.

```
 <span ref='B'><span ref='A'></span></span>   
//click event is on A, but I replaced the html inside of B to <span ref='A'></span>;  
its update, so the replaced html are the same.
```

I read many related problems, I found the solution are

```
.live() //  will not work
.delegate(), // work
.on(), // work
```

The solution is I should bind the event on B instead of A like `B.on('click', A, function(){})`....

However, my structure is very hard to change, I rather want to find a solution that can prevent lose events while replacing or alternative.

Please advice, thank you very much.

---

Solved by using detach()

Comment: What's the point of the replacement, if the replaced html is the same?

Answer (score 1):

Since event bindings exist within the context of DOM elements, when you start removing or replacing DOM elements, you need some mechanism to re-establish the event bindings.

A good approach is to use delegation via a parent element (as you have stated - `B.on('click', A, function(){})....` ).

The other alternative is to always re-establish the bindings at the point at which the DOM elements in question are removed or replaced (so in your scenario, it sounds like this would have to be in the Ajax callback/completion handler) however this is generally a poorer approach and is much less elegant than the delegation method.

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about applying the `on` event to a certain element on the page. Then I would recommend just binding the event to the `document`.

```
$(document).on('click', '#id-of-a', function(){

});
```

Read this [blog post](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/03/jquery-1-7-released/) for more information concerning this.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. This is possible with using  .detach()! tested.